# Resolving assets path in css with Angular 7 cli

Tags: css, angular, sass, command-line-interface, assets

I have an image (toolbar-bg.svg) in my assets folder, and trying to set it as the background image for an element. If I apply `background: url('assets/toolbar-bg.svg')` then it won't build because postcss can't resolve the file, but if I apply `background: url('../assets/toolbar-bg.svg')` it builds but then the path is wrong client side and it can't load the image. How do I get this to work properly?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 10):

Try These pathes

1. background: url('~/assets/toolbar-bg.svg')
2. background: url('/assets/toolbar-bg.svg')

If none of them worked then you better try physical adresses

Comment: "postcss" complains about every single thing I've tried except `../assets/toolbar-bg.svg` because that's where the file is, and it doesn't translate that path to the built output path of `/assets/toolbar-bg.svg`

Comment: `'~/assets/myimage.jpg'` worked for me using angular 7 and scss.  I had to delete my old css file it kept trying to use.  Then I had to change my styleUrls to point to the scss file instead of of the css file

Comment: Thanks @Arian. #2 worked for me and I am using `Angular 8`. Cheers.